# How can I sandbox the youtube iframes_api

Tags: javascript, security, youtube, sandbox, youtube-iframe-api

I'm trying to `<iframe sandbox>` the youtube iframe_api to prevent it from accessing sensitive data in the main window.

I have a sandboxed iframe that contains the js to invoke the api, but in order to get it to work, I need to give it `sandbox="allow-same-origin"` which defeats the entire purpose, giving it access to the main window. Please see the simplified codepen example.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qLJrxd

Is there another recommendation for sandboxing the API?

Comment: Did you find a way to do this?

Comment: I think we went with a window.postMessage() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage based solution